# Multiple domains in one hosting account

Tags: domains, web-hosting, shared-hosting

Several hosting services allow you to host multiple domains within a single hosting plan or account. For example, for Namecheap's Value package [ https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/shared.aspx] allows one to host up to 3 domains.

I currently have a hosting account and have a personal domain set up. I wish to add a second domain to the hosting account, for a charity I'm working on. However, there are other folks who is associated with the charity that I'd like to have access to the charity site, but not my person site.

Question:
I heard it's not possible to have separate cPanel passwords for the two domain if I'm only paying for one hosting account. Is this correct? Is it possible to have separate passwords for FTP and SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I heard it's not possible to have separate cPanel passwords for the two domain[s] if I'm only paying for one hosting account.

I assume you mean separate cPanel user logins with separate passwords. Unless your provider actively allows this, the answer is likely "No."

> Is it possible to have separate passwords for FTP and SSH?

Regarding SSH, this likely falls back on the hosting provider since not all providers enable SSH access.

Regarding FTP and WebDisk access, assuming your provider enables them, you should be able to add separate users with unique passwords for these services in cPanel under their respective sections (as of cPanel 54+ with the paper_lantern frontend, a consolidated email/ftp/webdisk "User Manager" section under "Preferences" may be also available). However, these are not cPanel logins.

Comment: Thanks Anaksunaman - I assume everything I need here can be done if get a "reseller hosting" account?

Comment: @Tosh Ideally, yes, since the point of a "reseller" account is to be able to "sell" additional cPanel logins. Reseller accounts typically have a limited subset of the WHM panel for this. Note, however, the features available in this WHM subset may be enabled/disabled by the provider so you will still likely want to do some research about what is available from any given host/package (ex. SSH).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the terms and conditions and type of hosting you use for the most part.

If you use a dedicated server, then you'll be able to have an entire cpanel interface in your control to the point where you can assign a different username/password to each domain and have as many domains as you want attached to the server.

If you use another hosting package, check their terms and conditions as they may have restrictions on what you can and can't do. You may want to ask the provider for the possibility of opening two separate accounts, one for each domain in order to have separate passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one domain and then make it subdomain.
Like stackexchange.com using webmasters.stackexchange.com and others.By using one domain only you make the subacategories.

Answer (score 1):

Subdomains in one account with cPanel is definitely possible. It's a feature that works quite well, actually.

Multiple domains in one cPanel account isn't gonna work. If you would still prefer some central management, maybe you should consider access to WHM.

Then again, this is all up to your hosting company. You should ask them.